Erasing from boost::concurrent_flat_map causes a crash
I'm working on a UDP server using the boost library. The server must keep track of "connected" users. These will be considered "not connected" if the server does not receive messages within a certain time limit (in this case 5 seconds). When a client times out, it must be removed from the client list.
The server works fine and I receive messages, however the application crashes when a client disconnects. I identified the problem in the erase function of the concurrent_flat_map but I can't understand why it happens...Below is the minimum code to reproduce the error:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered/concurrent_flat_map.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>


class UdpClient
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        UdpClient(int recv_id, std::function<void(int)> cb) :
            m_queue(100)
        {
            this->m_recv_id = recv_id;
            this->m_on_disconnected = cb;
            this->m_proc_thread = std::thread(std::bind(&UdpClient::handle_queue, this));
        }

        // Enqueue
        void enqueue(unsigned char* buffer) 
        {   
            if (this->m_queue.write_available() > 0)
            {
                this->m_queue.push(buffer);
                this->m_proc_cond.notify_one();
            }
        }

    private:

        int m_recv_id;    
        std::function<void(int)> m_on_disconnected;
        boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<unsigned char*> m_queue;
        std::condition_variable m_proc_cond;
        std::mutex              m_proc_mutex;
        std::thread             m_proc_thread;

        // Handle queue
        void handle_queue()
        {
            while (true) 
            {       
                while (this->m_queue.read_available() > 0)            
                {
                    this->m_queue.consume_one(
                        [&] (unsigned char* buffer)
                        {
                            // Process                  
                        }
                    );
                } 
              
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(this->m_proc_mutex);
                auto now     = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
                auto timeout = now + std::chrono::seconds(5);
                if (!this->m_proc_cond.wait_until(lk, timeout, [&] ()
                {
                    return this->m_queue.read_available() > 0;
                })) 
                {   
                    std::cout << "timeout occurs\n";
                    break;
                }
            } 
            
            // Cleanup messages queue
            this->m_queue.consume_all([] (unsigned char* buffer) { delete buffer; });

            // Notify disconnection
            this->m_on_disconnected(this->m_recv_id);
        }

};

class UdpServer
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        UdpServer(int port) : 
            m_ioservice(),    
            m_clients  (5)
        {
            this->m_port = port;
            this->m_socket = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>(m_ioservice);
        }

        // Listen
        void listen()
        {
            auto endpoint = boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), this->m_port);
            this->m_socket->open(endpoint.protocol());
            this->m_socket->set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
            this->m_socket->set_option(boost::asio::detail::socket_option::boolean<SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT>(true));
            this->m_socket->set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::keep_alive(true));
            this->m_socket->bind(endpoint);
            this->handle_receive();
            this->m_ioservice.run();
        }
    
    private:

        int m_port;
        boost::asio::io_service m_ioservice;    
        std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> m_socket;   
        std::thread m_listen_thread;      
        boost::concurrent_flat_map<int32_t, std::shared_ptr<UdpClient>> m_clients; 
        std::array<unsigned char, 1500> m_buffer {};
        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint m_remote_endpoint;

        // Handle receive
        void handle_receive() 
        {  
            this->m_socket->async_receive_from(
                boost::asio::buffer(this->m_buffer, 1500), 
                this->m_remote_endpoint,
                [this] (boost::system::error_code const & err, size_t num_bytes)
                {    
                    if (num_bytes > 0) 
                    {                
                        int recv_id = 1;
                        unsigned char buffer[num_bytes];
                        std::copy_n(std::begin(this->m_buffer), num_bytes, buffer);
                                                
                        if (this->m_clients.contains(recv_id))
                        {
                            this->m_clients.visit(recv_id,
                                [&] (std::pair<const int, std::shared_ptr<UdpClient>> &x)
                                {
                                    x.second->enqueue(buffer);
                                }
                            );                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            auto client = std::make_shared<UdpClient>(recv_id,
                                [&] (int id)
                                {
                                    std::cout << "received disconnect signal\n";
                                    if (this->m_clients.contains(id))
                                    {        
                                        // ---------- ERROR HERE ----------
                                        this->m_clients.erase(id);
                                        // --------------------------------
                                    }      
                                }
                            );
                            this->m_clients.insert(std::pair<int32_t, std::shared_ptr<UdpClient>>(recv_id, client));
                            client->enqueue(buffer);

                            std::cout << "connected clients = " << this->m_clients.size() << "\n";
                        }
                    }

                    // Continue receiving...
                    this->handle_receive();
                }
            );    
        }

};



int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{    
    auto server = new UdpServer(9000);
    server->listen();

    return 0;
}

To compile:
g++ -o test main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -ltb

To test it (on linux):
nc -u 127.0.0.1 9000 < /dev/random

run for 1 second and kill the process
NOTE: I'm using latest version of boost (1.85.0)
I've tried to use a try ... catch but doesn't works...

I'm very confused why you added complicated locking and synchronization around a lockfree queue. Also, enqueing a local array (of variable length even, which is non-standard or ill-formed) is definitely UB since you cannot delete that. Also, this seems to call for signals OR weak pointers instead of the lifetime entangled "on_disconnected".

Trivia: Asio already sets SO_REUSEPORT for portability on platforms that requires it (OSX, BSDs, QNX).

Solved! Seems that someone is locking the shared_ptr. Switching from:
boost::concurrent_flat_map<int32_t, std::shared_ptr<UdpClient>>

to:
boost::concurrent_flat_map<int32_t, UdpClient*>

solved the issue

I think your diagnosis is wrong and simply hides other Undefined Behavior. Compare with this simplifying version: https://godbolt.org/z/PTo511YE1

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
